# reloading IFRAME with jQuery not showing changes OR failing to load CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an iframe on page '1' which shows a separate page '2' within my site.

Page 1 contains a form that runs an AJAX function on submission. This calls a PHP file which edits specific parts of Page 2 based upon what was entered in the form.

In the success callback of the AJAX function, I'm reloading the iframe on Page 1 like so:

```
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'file.php',
               data: "user="+ user +"&title="+ title,
               success: function()
               {
                    var frameHtml = '<iframe id="previewFrame" src="temp/' + user + '/" width="100%" height="373" scrolling="yes"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>';
                    var liveDemoFrame = $('.liveDemoFrame');
                    var previewFrame = $('#previewFrame');

                    previewFrame.remove();
                    liveDemoFrame.append(frameHtml).hide();
                    $('#previewFrame').hide();
                    liveDemoFrame.show().append('<div class="customiseThemeSpinnerWrap"><div class="customiseThemeSpinnerIcon"></div></div>');

                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        $('#loading').remove();
                        $('.customiseThemeSpinnerWrap').remove();
                        $('#previewFrame').fadeIn();
                    }, 1000);
               }
        });
```

- In Firefox - once the iframe has reloaded, the CSS is missing and the page is purely HTML.
- In IE - the changes havn't been made.
- In Chrome - It works absolutely fine on my home PC and my test PC. But didn't work on University computers!

If I visit Page 2 without the iframe, the changes HAVE been made and it works fine!

I've tried adding:

```
<meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: lots of unusual activity in this ajax call...remove an item then hide it, show() for an item just created and success isn't dependent on any data

Comment: You're absolutely right. Removing all of the crap has fixed it in Firefox and IE. Now I just need to re-code the fadeIn animations differently.

Comment: my guess is you don't even need to make an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Cache? try setting the no cache http headers using the header function. you can also append a random number to the back of the url using jquery so that proxies will not cache them too.

Am answering from my mobile phone, so it is not easy to provide examples. sorry.

Comment: I've tried adding some meta info to disable cache (as seen in the updated op) but that didn't help. 

Do you mean append a random number to the iframe URL?

Comment: Yup. use the math.random function. also for the meta infinitely, try also using the header php function to set those. I believe the documentation for that function has example on how to set them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by the "$('#previewFrame').hide();" being inside the success function. Not that it's any help to anyone but thought I'd post how I solved this anyway :)